# Multiple SELECT, Avoid duplicate results for one table in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select from two tables where table 1 returns 1 row and table 2 returns multiple rows resulting in NO duplicates from table 1?
Below, page.title has one row.   page_images.image_loc can have anything from 1 to 10.  If page_images.image_loc has 2 or more, page.title will be duplicated for the count of page_images.image_loc rows.  How can I limit page.title to 1, but not page_images.image_loc?

```
$query = mysql_query("
                      SELECT page.title,
                      page_images.image_loc
                      FROM page, page_images
                      WHERE page.url_category = '$category' AND
                      page.url_title = page_images.page_title
                    ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `SELECT page.title, GROUP_CONCAT(page_images.image_loc) AS image_locs ... GROUP BY page.title` to collect all the `image_loc` values in one row, then separate the list with `explode()`.